# Is there a way to configure all cookies to be HttpOnly in Google AppEgine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I'm using Google AppEngine platform in Python and for security reasons I'm looking for a way to configure all cookies to be HttpOnly. I mean, what I'm trying to do is to make every cookie the platform uses to be HttpOnly, and I have been told that it might be a way yo do it generally, like a "cookie generator", but I'm not able to find it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most frameworks give you methods to create cookies, and `HttpOnly` support is pretty standard. If you're using `webapp2` [this method](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies) is available:

```
# Saves a cookie in the client.
response.set_cookie('some_key', 'value', max_age=360, path='/', httponly=True)
```

But cookies are nothing magical, it's just a string with some [simple format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), so you will always be able to do something like this:

```
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", "some_key=value; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT; HttpOnly")
```

Comment: The first method is what I found to do with individual cookies, so I was looking for something general, if any. And the second one I see is more or less similar to the first, for individual cookies, I guess.

Anyway, thank you for your response, I'm going to use that for now.

Comment: The second one is the most general, you're explicitly setting the header of the response, something you'll be able to do with any http library.